# RANK in the column for unknown number of rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am in the very beginning with VBA programming.
I would like to ask you how to add a rank function to calculate rank for the data in the whole column. 
I have data in column B and I want to rank it in column A.

Now I can do it for 1 line (A2) but I want macro to continue until there is an empty row in column B and I do not want to type a strict range in the query because there is a possibility, that more rows will be added in the future.

Please, can you help me? 
You are the best! Thank you in advance

Comment: Provide sample data. Your actual data and expected data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
  Dim N As Long
  N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  Range("A2:A" & N).Formula = "=rank(B2,B$2:B" & N & ")"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for :)